# Custom code to fix #Error showing in SSRS reports

Tags: vb.net, function, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a few reports built using Report Builder 3 for MSSQL 2008 Reporting Services.
Some fields in my report are showing "#Error", instead of this I want to show only a simple "-". Is there any built-in function or custom code to overcome this?

Comment: +1 for the question, but still I have to ask: fixing the errors is not an option?

Comment: This is not an option as I am using Previous function, thus for the first row it will always show #Error, which I need to fix and show only a "-".

Comment: Can you elaborate on the circumstances giving the #Error, like the formula causing it and conditions under which it happens?

Comment: Second @ChrisLatta, the [Previous function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156372%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) returns `Nothing` if there is no previous item. You can just check for that situation and deal with it accordingly in your expression to prevent the #Error from even occurring.

Comment: I have tried this iif(IsNothing(Previous(Fields!MyField.Value)), "-", Previous(Fields!MyField.Value))..but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I assume you tried `IsError()` as well and it didn't work? I've tried to reproduce this on my environment and the Previous function just returns a blank value, so IsNothing works for me.

Comment: Tried IsError(), but still it shows "#Error".

Comment: Any chance that formatting is applied to the result and that's where the #Error is coming from? In the rdl file, phrases like <Format>D0</Format> will show up as #Error.

Answer (score 0):

I'd still really like to see your formula but you seem determined not to show it, so I'll take a wild stab at answering without it. I imagine that you are doing something like dividing the field on the current row by the field on the previous row. However, this would give you `Infinity` on the first line rather than `#Error` so there is something else going on. But let's run with this anyway since we don't have your formula.

The most common way to solve this is to check for Nothing being returned for the Previous function, usually indicating that you are on the first row (assuming your field always has data). This has the advantage of also working on fields that are not guaranteed to have a value.

```
 =IIF(IsNothing(Previous(Fields!MyField.Value)), "-", Fields!MyField.Value / Previous(Fields!MyField.Value))
```

Here is another way you could do it using the row number, which will always check for the first row regardless:

```
=IIF(RowNumber(Nothing) = 1, "-", Fields!MyField.Value / Previous(Fields!MyField.Value))
```

This assumes that the error is being caused by the Value formula and not by some other mechanism such as applying an expression to other properties like Format, Color which is invalid when there is no previous row.